# Rails 4 Multiple nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

i'm trying to create a multiple nested form I have been following this example
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

here we have

- Person > has_many :addresses
- Address > belong_to :person

But if I want to add the City table I would have

- Person > has_many :addresses
- Address > belongs_to :person, belongs_to :city
- City > has_many :addresses

The problem comes when I try to add in the form the field City as a text_field NOT as a select. All of the examples I've seen use select instead.

What I want to do is to have a form to create a Person, allow the Person to insert Address and display City as a text field. If the city doesn't exist in the database then create it, if not use the existing one (I guess here I will have to use find_or_create_by?).

**Person**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

**Address**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :city
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :city
end
```

**City**

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end
```

I dont know how to handle the person params, I have this:

```
def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, addresses_attributes: [:id, :kind, :street, cities_attributes: [:id, :city]])
  end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  Addresses:
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |addresses_form| %>
      <li>
        <%= addresses_form.label :kind %>
        <%= addresses_form.text_field :kind %>

        <%= addresses_form.label :street %>
        <%= addresses_form.text_field :street %>

        <%= addresses_form.fields_for :cities do |cities_form| %>
           <%= cities_form.label :city %>
           <%= cities_form.text_field :city %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

When i try to add the city i get this error

```
Unpermitted parameters: cities
```

And it doesn't add the city to the database nor the Address.

I have been trying to solve this for a while and I haven't able to find a solution. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your **`Person`** model.

Comment: I modified the original post to show the 3 models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `city_attributes`.
An address doesn't `have_many :cities`, just one. :)

Likewise, you must change the `Address` so that it `belongs_to :city` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :city`

Comment: Thats how I have it now

Comment: Your code above does not have it that way. it has `accepts_nested_attributes_for :cities` note the pluralisation. it should instead be `accepts_nested_attributes_for :city` You also have `cities_attributes: [:id, :city]` and that should be: `city_attributes: [:id, :city]`

Comment: I finally understood what you were traying to say, and it worked! Thanks genius